# WordPress Custom Fields tab gone after installing ACF Pro plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, webhooks, acfpro

I want to change some custom WooCommerce checkout fields (created by a checkout plugin) and these are stored as original WordPress custom fields.

But because I have installed the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, the original Custom Fields tab is gone.

I tried to add the following code to my function.php without any result:

`add_filter('acf/settings/remove_wp_meta_box', '__return_false');`

Just to be sure I deactivated the ACF Pro plugin to be 100% sure this was the issue and the tabs where back :)

Anyone an other idea to get the original Custom Fields tab back?

Comment: Hey there, did you by chance figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Your priority might not be enough. Try like this.

```
add_filter('acf/settings/remove_wp_meta_box', '__return_false', 20);
```

**EDIT**

Please try to initialize ACF with this code

```
function my_acf_init() {
    acf_update_setting('remove_wp_meta_box', false);
}

add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');
```

Comment: Many thx for your quick reply. Unfortunately it didn't work. I also tried higher and lower numbers without any result.

Comment: Can you try to install `Code Snippets` plugin and try to add the filter with that? Maybe there is something else that's affecting your functions.php https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

Comment: Tnx. I already have installed Code Snippets :) and I always add code via the plugin like that.

Comment: @YorlinqNL I edited my answer. Please try the edited code

Comment: I'm sorry no this also doesn't work. Appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was registering a custom post type without declaring support for `custom-fields`. The other answers would have worked for standard pages.

```
$books_args =[
  'supports' => [ 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'custom-fields' ]
];
register_post_type( 'book', $books_args );
```

Obviously you would need to adapt this this to your custom post type